# Spanning Tree Protocol

Tags: протоколы

Зачем придумали протокол Spanning Tree, точнее какую проблему он решает?И что такое широковещательные пакеты - зачем они гуляют по сети и откуда беруться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот протокол решает проблему множественных связей в сети. То-есть, если в сети есть кольцевые структуры (грубо говоря от одного свитча до другого можно пройти несколькими разными кабелями), то коммутаторы отключают те связи, которые на данный момент избыточны.

Это делается для того чтобы пакеты по кругу не ходили.

Если вдруг нечто деструктивное настигнет один из линков и он прекратит передавать данные, коммутаторы найдут обходной (альтернативный) путь прохода в обход повреждения (если такой путь есть)

А широковещательные пакеты - это такие пакеты которые идут сразу всем получателям, подключенным к данному сегменту сети. В них указывается мак-адрес назначения FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF